# fitting and predicting model with mlflow

Tags: python, mlflow

I'm very new to understanding the use of MLFlow but need assistance, I'm trying to understand on how to try and fit and predict my model once again. I'm able to call my model by:

```
PLS_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model("runs:/FFFFF!@#!@#@!#!/logged_model", suppress_warnings = True)
```

and get:

```
mlflow.pyfunc.loaded_model:
  artifact_path: logged_model
  flavor: mlflow.sklearn
  run_id: FFFFF!@#!@#@!#!
```

But when I try to call any methods as:

1).fit or .predict. I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'PyFuncModel' object has no attribute 'fit'

AttributeError: 'PyFuncModel' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

Here I encountered on how to actually call these functions but not sure if I'm doing this correctly. In summary, how can I predict, fit to my new data.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try to use sklearn model loader

```
import mlflow.sklearn
model = mlflow.sklearn.load_model(..)
model.predict(...)
```

Comment: thanks this was actually what worked, I realized I was working on an older version of mflow then the current one. thanks!